# NTFS File shows as directory

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ntfs

I have a WD Passport external disk formated in NTFS. I either use it attached to my laptop or to a WD TVLive multimédia player.

After a fews days conencted to the TVLive, some of the files are showing up in Windows as Folders/Directory, instead of files. This happens to hundreds of my family photos (JPG files).
I would like to recover those photos.

I tried using all kinds of CHKDSK to no avail. I even tried TestDisk but there was no way to recover normal file status to my photos. I tried recreating the NTFS Hard Link to the file using TCC/LE (http://jpsoft.com/help/index.htm?mklink.htm) using the command "mklink /H /X filepath filepath".

Using Directory Snoop NTFS Module (http://www.briggsoft.com/dsnoop.htm) I was able to see that the file is still there. For this software it is considered a file, not a folder. I was even able to recover some of the photos. The trouble is there are hundreds and this is pretty tedious work. Do you know of a batch/fast way of solving this problem?

Thank you very much,
Joel

Comment: " ... showing up in Windows as folders/directories ... " is rather vague. Have you tried using the Dir command in the Command Prompt? Windows Explorer is rather prone to inexact representation of actual disk contents, and if there are third-party shell extensions involved, almost anything goes.

Comment: @kreemoweet either Dir command Prompt or Windows explorer or whatever sftware you use, the "file" is shown as a folder.
There are no third-party Shell extensions involved here.

Answer (score 0):

Well, besides variety of possible approaches (which could be fine as well) to solve this problem I would recommend to try software supposed to recover deleted and erased pictures and even formatted disks, which I believe scans your disk sector by sector bypassing file system table and looking for chains of graphic data anyways. I can't remember all names I worked with many years ago, but search in google offered a number of fresh ones, such as: CardRecovery, Wondershare Photo Recovery, Deleted Pictures Recovery Pro 2.9.2 (free trials).

By the way, what is your intuition about having a risk that your machine is infected by viruses. From the perspective to prevent further loss, would not it be better to load the machine from save environment?

Comment: Hi @Ruslan. I will check those applications. There is no vírus involved. This corruption happens only when the disk is connected to the Western Digital TV Live media player.
I think it may be because we leave the disk and the player connected for days on end or my daughters disconnecting the disk without turning off the player.